# Wildcard and search syntax formatting on peewee and python

Tags: python, orm, syntax, peewee

Trying to refactor out keywordAlt bit in collectionsQuery

```
def countSubject(genres):
    for keyword in genres:  
        keywordAlt = '%'+keyword+'%'
        collectionsQuery = Collection.select().join(Subject).where(Subject.name ** keywordAlt, Subject.name != 'librivox', Subject.name != 'spoken',  Subject.name != 'audiobook', Collection.downloads > 50)
        if collectionsQuery.count() > 5:
            print keyword, collectionsQuery.count()
```

I am refactoring this snippit, and want to first remove the keywordAlt bit and include the text in my query.  However

```
        collectionsQuery = Collection.select().join(Subject).where(Subject.name ** '%'+keyword+'%', Subject.name != 'librivox', Subject.name != 'spoken',  Subject.name != 'audiobook', Collection.downloads > 50)
```

However, using the second method, it matches everything.

```
        collectionsQuery = Collection.select().join(Subject).where(Subject.name ** %keyword%, Subject.name != 'librivox', Subject.name != 'spoken',  Subject.name != 'audiobook', Collection.downloads > 50)
```

This is interpreted as a wildcard search for "keyword"

What is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I think I see the problem... It has to do with python's operator precedence.

Try this:

```
collectionsQuery = (Collection
                    .select()
                    .join(Subject)
                    .where(
                        Subject.name ** ('%' + keyword + '%'),
                        # rest of query here ...
                    ))
```